# Partially replace regex pattern in string using gsub in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have to replace " used as a unit of measure (inches) in strings that also contain characters in double quotes.

```
uuuu<- c('BELT, "V" 5L610, LONG 4.5" WIDE 7.5", TYPE "K"')
```

The vector in my data has 70k+ rows, I only need to worry about the " right after numbers. 
my desired results would be - `BELT, "V" 5L610, LONG 4.5IN WIDE 7.5IN, TYPE "K"`

I tried `gsub('\\d\"',"\\dIN",uuuu)` but you know that's not going to give me the result correct result: `"BELT, \"V\" 5L610, LONG 4.dIN WIDE 7.dIN, TYPE \"K\"`

Then I tried grep to find the pattern and get the indices, however, that doesn't seem to reasonable since a single string in the vector could have both " as a UOM and as a quote. `grep('\\d\"',uuuu,value = FALSE)`

How do I retain the digit from my pattern? It should be possible in gsub?

Comment: Maybe `gsub('(\\d)"', "\\1IN", uuuu)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, I have come across 1,2 before in Regex. But I was not able to find a reference where I can learn about exactly what they are? can you share a reference? If you want I'll the accept the solution if posted.

Comment: This [website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) is one of my favorites

Comment: @Poppinyoshi See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (a pair of unescaped parentheses) around the part of the pattern you need to keep after replacement and a [**backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the group value inside the replacement pattern:

```
gsub('(\\d)"', "\\1IN", uuuu)
      ^   ^     ^^^
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/TVv0VK/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(\d)` - Capturing group 1 (whose value can be referenced to with a `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern): any digit
- `"` - a double quote.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/aOSamP):

```
uuuu<- c('BELT, "V" 5L610, LONG 4.5" WIDE 7.5", TYPE "K"')
cat(gsub('(\\d)"', "\\1IN", uuuu))
## => BELT, "V" 5L610, LONG 4.5IN WIDE 7.5IN, TYPE "K"
```